# Class 'App\Controller\Debugger' not found error with cakephp ver3

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0.2. I tried to use `Debugger::dump($date_taken_year);` and encountered the error `Error: Class 'App\Controller\Debugger' not found`. If I remove the line that uses `Debugger::dump()`, the error disappears and the controller function runs smoothly.

I have checked that inside app.php, I have this line `'debug' => true,`. Do I have to do anything else to use Debugger class? I had no problems when using cakephp ver2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you only forgot to import namespace, proper use would be

```
use Cake\Error\Debugger;
// ...
Debugger::dump($date_taken_year);
```