# How to do Password hashing in cakephp 3 manually?

Tags: hash, cakephp-3.0

I am working on forgot password and i want to send the new password using rand() . After sending the password to customer email i want to update the new password with hashing but i do not know how to do this ? Please help me to solve this ?

code:

```
$hash = Security::hash('CakePHP Framework');
```

> error : Class 'App\Controller\Security' not found

Comment: its simple before hashing store it in a variable or updated your db

Comment: I want to save it with hashing so next time use can login using new password and if the password is not hashed so user is not able to login using new password , i want to know about the function which can hash the new password ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585222/using-md5-for-password-hash-in-auth-component-of-cakephp-2-x duplicate question

Comment: but how to use it in cakephp 3

Comment: did you try it i think it will work

Comment: It gives the error sercurity not found ?

Comment: can you add that error in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'App\Controller\Debugger' not found error with cakephp ver3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069894/class-app-controller-debugger-not-found-error-with-cakephp-ver3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the following line in the controller.

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
```

Now you can use the following code to hash your password manually.

```
$password = "Your Password";
$hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
$hasher->hash($password);
```

Comment: I wonder why it is giving me different hashes everytime I run the code.

Comment: @RjQuery It adds timestamp every time.